# Как создать shared library?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Мне дали задание. Надо создать проект, где будет 2 библиотеки, одна из них должна быть динамической. Не могу понять, как собрать все с помощью cmake. Надо ли обязательно создавать 2 проекта для этого? Или можно все сделать в одно проекте и одном cmake файле. Сами функции в библиотеках могут быть любыми.

Answer (score 1):

> как собрать все с помощью cmake?

В файл CMakeLists.txt вставляем команды для сборки библиотек:

```
# Обычная библиотека
add_library(<Имя библиотеки>
...
Список файлов С для этой библиотеки
...
}

# Разделяемая библиотека
add_library(<Имя библиотеки> SHARED
...
Список файлов С для этой библиотеки
...
}
```

Разница заключается в слове *SHARED*.